# process text file in ksh append data

Tags: regex, sed, ksh

Following doesn't work. 
I need to add a , and an input param at the end of the script. Please help

```
#!/bin/ksh

data_log="/usr/data/data_log.dbg"
err_file="/usr/data/data_log.err"

if [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
    inParam=$1
fi

processInfo ${inParam} > ${data_log}

#Append ,inParam to each line in log for further processing
for logger in `cat ${data_log}`
{
    echo ${logger} | sed s/$/,${inParam}/ >> ${err_file}
}

rm -rf ${data_log}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the `for logger in` loop where you're reading the file with this:

```
cat ${data_log} | while read line
do
    echo "${line},${inParam}" >> ${err_file}
done
```

...which I think can be written like this (no shell to test with at the moment) to [avoid a UUOC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat)...

```
while read line
do
    echo "${line},${inParam}" >> ${err_file}
done < ${data_log}
```